# Create react app structure like create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I would like to create a package that will create a custom structure, like create-react-app does to create a react app. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unclear question, are you asking how to make a template? Because a template is not a package and package is not a library, which one you trying to build?

Comment: CRA has done it, so clearly the answer is "yes". Can you be more specific about what you've tried and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make a template, but with an npm package like create-react-app.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I know how to create a library of components and publish it to a registry, but I don't understand how create-react-app works to create a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a **template** you just need to host your code (like github) and reuse it.

But I assume you want to build **a template for CRA**, see [Building a Template](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates/#building-a-template) in docs.